# looking for patterns in a dictionary and make a new dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a list of all combinations of sequences can be made with `'K'`
 and `'M'` and the lengths are from 6 to 18. so, I have combinations
 including `"KKKKKK"` to `"MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"`.
 I have also a dictionary in which the keys are ids and the values are
 long sequences made not only with K and M but also with some more
 characters which are not important for me.

small example:

```
 com = ["KKKKKK", "KKKKKM", ......, "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"]
 li = {id1: "KKKKKKHKJASGKKKMOOGBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM",
 id2:"MMKFJDFKFGKJJJJFKKKKKMJKJHFKKKKKK"}
```

I want to find different combinations in the `li` dictionary(values) and
 make a new dictionary in which the keys are ids from `li` dictionary
 (the keys) and values are a list containing the combinations found in
 the values of li dictionary. for the small example the output would be
 like this:

```
results = {id1: ["KKKKKK", "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"], id2: ["KKKKKM", "KKKKKK"] }
```

I wrote the following code but did not give me what I want.

```
results = {}
 for i in com:
     if i in li.values():
         results[li.keys()] = [i]
```

Comment: Could you please check the re module (regular expression module) that gives you a match in case the string is found within the li string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` within a dictionary comprehension:

```
In [11]: {k: re.findall(r'(?:K|M){6,18}', v) for k, v in li.items()}
Out[11]: {'id1': ['KKKKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM'], 'id2': ['KKKKKM', 'KKKKKK']}
```

`r'(?:K|M){6,18}'` is a regular expression that will match any substring of `K` or `M` with length 6 to 18.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `if i in li.values():`. This line will check if any of the dictionary's values equals the current combination. Instead, you want this:

```
if v in li.values():
    if i in v:
```

Which will check if any of the dict's values contains the current combination.
Also, this line `results[li.keys()] = [i]` will map all of the dict's keys to a new list. There are two problems with that: first, you want to map only the relevant key. Second, you want to add to the current list, not replace it with a new one.